# WSO2 API Manager theme customization

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

as per AM documentation, https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme, themes can be modified by including new/subthems, but in store/publisher css/images are referred from `repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\site\themes\wso2\libs\theme-wso2_1.0`, is there any official recommendation on how to modify themes under libs or how the changes made under `repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/subthemes` will be reflected in libs/themes

please clarify

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually the recommended way of editing the theme is using the sub themes. So that it overrides the main theme css and applies the edited subtheme styling to the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try sub themes option, but issues some of the images are not picked from themes folder (store\site\themes), these are referred from (store\site\themes\wso2\libs\theme-wso2_1.0\images) folder ex. https://localhost:9443/store/site/themes/wso2/libs/theme-wso2_1.0/images/logo-inverse.svg. This is displayed at top left corner of store/publish application.